# Forecasting Error while using tabts function in r

Tags: r, forecasting

I am trying to use tbats function in r.
My data points are below

backlog
[1] 1.04 1.06 1.08 1.08

But, I tried to execute tbats function on above vector

```
backlogts <- tbats(backlog)
```

But I am getting below error

```
Error in optim(par = param.vector$vect, fn = calcLikelihoodNOTransformed,  : 
  function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters
```

Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: I don't get an error using forecast v8.3. Try updating your packages. In any case, if you are going to report an error, at least provide package versions using sessionInfo()

Comment: @RobHyndman, Thanks for your reply. I checked version it is forecast_7.1, I tried to install package from github https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast, but getting error and not able to install forecast library (Error : object 'ch.test' is not exported by 'namespace:uroot'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'forecast'
* removing 'C:/Users/nilesh.ulhas.hulyal/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/forecast'
Error: Command failed (1)) , Can you please advice how I can install forecast v8.3 package?

Comment: just update from CRAN

Comment: @RobHyndman, I checked on CRAN https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html but latest I can see version 8.2 for forecast package not able to view version 8.3, Can you please advice from where I can install version 8.3

Comment: Install v8.3 from github, or v8.2 from CRAN. Or wait a week and v8.3 will be on CRAN.